# In highchart Y-axis plotline labels get cut off

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, bar-chart

I want to create barchart having custom horizontal lines added to show average benchmarks. Also there is labels added on these lines to show benchmark heading. I get line labels cut off as shown in following image.
[Barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pPXP.png)

Also if plot line value is beyond the range plotted, plot line get hidden. How to handle this case in highchart? Following is the code that I am using.

```js
$(function () { 
    $('#chartContainer').highcharts({
     credits: {
         enabled: false
     },
     colors: ['#3C791D','#BEBEBE','#7F7F7F'],
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        }, 
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Great', 'Neutral', 'Bad']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotLines:[{
                value:80,
                color: '#000000',
                width:2,
                zIndex:4,
                label:{
                 text:'XYZ Average: 80%',
                 align: 'right'
                }
            },{
                value:60,
                color: '#000000',
                width:2,
                zIndex:4,
                label:{
                 text:'PQR Average: 60%',
                 align: 'right'
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
         enabled : false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter:function() {
                     return this.y + '%';
                    }
                },
                colorByPoint: true,
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
         type: 'column',
         name: "s",
            data: [70, 10, 40]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Highcharts will not automatically make room for these labels like it will some others. You will need to account for this yourself, either by your positioning of the label, or by increasing the space available - I would set a **topMargin** to allow for the label: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.marginTop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set height for the chart and also the max value for Y-axis

```js
chart: {
  height: 600
},
yAxis: {
  min: 0,
  max: 100
}
```

Comment: Setting max value is the trick, because marker lines drawn on range value may fall outside the range actually plotted on chart. I had used the same trick for jasper charts (jfreechart) earlier.